# Actualización de lectura de fichero CSV en PHP

Tags: php, csv

¡Hola y gracias por anticipado!

Tengo que generar un PHP para insertar entradas y leerlas a la vez, pero no consigo que me actualice cuando presiono "insertar".
En este caso, se trata de usuarios. Comienzo con un login para acceder, compruebo que el usuario existe y después paso a ver la página con los usuarios, que tiene un registro de usuario nuevo al final. Compruebo que no exista y, en teoría, si no hay errores, debería aparecer en cuanto lo inserto, pero lo único que ocurre es que hasta que no presiono insertar de nuevo, no aparece en la lista. Lo cierto es que no sé cómo hacer para que se "actualice" en cuanto presiono "insertar".

Dejo aquí mi código:

```
<?php

$error='';
$usuarios=array();
$pswds=array();

$archivo="usuarios.csv";
    if(!file_exists("usuarios.csv")) {
        $archivo = fopen("usuarios.csv", "rw");
        fclose($archivo);
    }
    if (!$fp = fopen($archivo,"rw")) {
    echo "No se pudo abrir el archivo.";
    } else {
        while(($datos=fgetcsv($fp))==true) {
            foreach ($datos as $clave=>$valor) {
                if ($clave==0) {
                    array_push($usuarios, $valor);
                } else if ($clave==1) {
                    array_push($pswds, $valor);
                }
            }
        }   
        fclose($fp);
        }

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $usuario=$_POST['user'];
    $pswd=$_POST['pswd'];
    if (empty($usuario)){
        $error='Debe introducir un usuario.';
        formulario($error);
    } else if (empty($pswd)) {
        $error='Debe introducir una contraseña.';
        formulario($error);
    } else {
            $valido=0;
            for ($i=0;$i<count($usuarios);$i++) {
                if ($usuario==$usuarios[$i]&&$pswd==$pswds[$i]) {
                    $valido=1;
                }
            }
            if ($valido==1){
                verUsuarios($usuarios, $pswds);
            } else {
                echo "<div id='error'>El usuario o la contraseña introducidos no son correctos.</div>";
            }
        }
} else {
    if (!isset($_POST['insertar'])) {
        formulario($error);
    } else {
        verUsuarios($usuarios,$pswds);
    }
}


function formulario ($error) {
    echo "<div id='acceder'>
        <form action='' method='post'>
        <h1>Acceder</h1>";
    if (!empty($error)) {
        echo "<div id='error'>".$error."</div>";
    }
    echo "<br><span id='texto'>Usuario</span><br>
            <input type='text' name='user' id='txtUser'/>
            <p>
            <br><span id='texto'>Contraseña</span><br>
            <input type='password' name='pswd' id='txtPswd'/>
            <br><p>
            <input type='submit' name='enviar' value='ENTRAR' id='enviar'/>
        </form>
    </div>";
}


function verUsuarios($usuarios, $pswds) {

    foreach ($usuarios as $clave=>$valor) {
        echo "<br>".$usuarios[$clave];
        echo "<br>".$pswds[$clave];
    }
    $errorN="";
    echo "<div id='formulario'>
        <p><form action='' method='post'>
            <h1>Insertar Usuario</h1>";
    if (isset($_POST['insertar'])){

        $usuarioN=$_POST['userN'];
        $pswdN=$_POST['pswdN'];
        if (empty($usuarioN)){
            $errorN='Debe introducir un usuario.';
        } else if (empty($pswdN)) {
            $errorN='Debe introducir una contraseña.';
        }
        foreach ($usuarios as $clave=>$valor) {
            if ($usuarioN==$valor) {
                $errorN='Ese nombre de usuario ya existe.';
            }
        }

        if (!empty($errorN)) {
            echo "<div id='error'>".$errorN."</div>";
        } else {
            $linea = array($usuarioN, $pswdN);
            $archivo2=fopen("usuarios.csv","a");
            fputcsv($archivo2,$linea);
            fclose($archivo2);
        }

    }
    echo"<br><span id='texto'>Usuario</span><br>
            <input type='text' name='userN' id='txtUser'/>
            <p>
            <br><span id='texto'>Contraseña</span><br>
            <input type='password' name='pswdN' id='txtPswd'/>
            <br><p>
            <input type='submit' name='insertar' value='INSERTAR' id='enviar'/>
        </form>
    </div>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Hola. Parece muy enredada tu solución, ¿pensaste en mejor convertir el csv en un array y recorrerlo de una manera más simple?

Comment: Sí que lo pensé, y de hecho también lo llevé a cabo, pero el problema está en que al tener que mostrar uno u otro formulario en caso de según si estoy entrando al programa o insertando, me sigue dando el mismo problema :S